# Reading a transducer sensitivity from its datasheet

Tags: sensitivity

How can I calculate the sensitivity of [this](https://www.crlsensors.com/prodDocs/sa-107ln.pdf) transducer? I also read at a text "The sensitivity is typically rated in terms of mV/g or pC/g, it is valid only at one frequency, conventionally at 100 Hz."

But in the datasheet only the range is given lets say for +-0.1G version if I map it  to +-7.5V. So how is the sensitivity calculated?

But my actual question is if we calculate the sensitivity it is not indicated at which frequency it is valid. How can we conclude on that by looking at datasheet at least in terms of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sensitivity is the output voltage range divided by the acceleration range. So  if you have the ±0.1 g version of the part, with an output voltage of ±7.5 V, then the sensitivity is:

$$ {7.5\:\mathrm V \over 0.1 g} = 75\:\mathrm V/g $$

This is a very high sensitivity as far as accelerometers go, but then these are marketed as "high sensitivity" devices with a "high level output", and this is the most sensitive device they make.

The datasheet specifies a "natural frequency" of "100 to 200 Hz, dependent upon range", so we can surmise sensitivity is highest somewhere in this range. In the datasheet I don't see anything more specific, so I suppose you'd need to either measure it yourself, look for a datasheet more specific to the particular part you've ordered, or contact the manufacturer for more detailed information.